# Setting member variables of Prototype class in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, prototypejs

```
var MyClass = (function() {    
  function MyClass(m) {
    this.m = m;
  }

  MyClass.prototype.temp = function() {
    process.nextTick(function() {
      console.log(m);
    });
  }
});

for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
  var t = new MyClass(i);
}
```

The code above always overwrites the private variables initialized in other instances. It displays 2, 2, 2 instead of 0, 1, 2. Are the member variables `m` set appropriately this way?

Yet it works fine without `process.nextTick`. Any idea?

Comment: Is this the actual code? It's either wrong, or there's stuff missing (part of the IIFE and a return statement).

Comment: The code is definitely incomplete...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code example is incomplete, however I believe your real code still suffers the following issue:

```
process.nextTick(function() {
    console.log(m); //where does the m variable came from?
});
```

Change your code to:

```
process.nextTick((function() {
    console.log(this.m);
}).bind(this));
```

`bind` is used to ensure that the `this` value inside the `nextTick` callback is the current `MyClass` instance.

Comment: Thanks @plalx for the solution. I actually used coffeescript to build the js class. It seems pretty tedious to have bind(this) at the end of callbacks (e.g. callback of async.queue). Do you know any better patterns?

Comment: @Unmeow I think you can use the `=>` operator in CoffeeScript to achieve the same effect. `process.nextTick(() => console.log(@m))`